# HTTP headers Content-Type for opening pdf,docx,doc,xls in a web browser

Tags: php, http-headers, content-type

I trying  a HTTP  content type that can both open both pdf,docx,doc,xls,pptx,  and preview then in web browser

I have tried these but they are not working

```
 //This is opening pdf only 

header('Content-Type:application/pdf');

//This is downloading the document 

header('Content-Type:application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text');
```

Comment: Have you looked at [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition), more specifically "**_Content-Disposition: inline_**"?